# Select primary or next best record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables holding information about contacts and there addresses.

```
Contact
  id
  name
  dob
  etc...

Address
 line1
 line2
 postcode
 etc...

ContactAddress
  contact_id
  address_id
  primary
```

I am trying to work out how to get a list of contacts and a single address. This address should be the primary where available (primary set to true), a secondary address if there is one available or blank data if neither are available.

Obviously using a group by on ContactAddress gives me one address per Contact but how do I prioritize those addresses flag as primary.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick...

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.DOB, a.Line1, a.Line2, a.Postcode
FROM Contact c
INNER JOIN ContactAddress ca ON c.Id = ca.Contact_Id
INNER JOIN [Address] a ON ca.Address_Id = a.Id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT c.Id AS Contact_Id,
        (SELECT TOP 1 Address_Id FROM ContactAddress WHERE Contact_Id=c.Id ORDER BY [Primary] DESC) AS Address_Id
    FROM Contact c) x
ON ca.Contact_Id = x.Contact_Id and ca.Address_Id = x.Address_Id

UNION

SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.DOB, null, null, null
FROM Contact c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ContactAddress WHERE Contact_Id=c.Id)
```